# Order rows of Data Table based on non null values of different columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like

```
id  colA  ColB  ColC  COlD 
1   10    Null  Null  100 
2   Null  2     Null  200 
3   Null  Null  7     500
```

and so on

what i need is if i select the values from the table like

```
select * from Table where ColC = 7 or ColB = 2 or ColA = 10
```

i will get the resul as

```
10    Null   Null 100
Null  2      Null 200
Null  Null   7    500
```

but i want the result as

```
Null  Null  7    500
Null  2     Null 200
10    Null  Null 100
```

So i could select value of `ColD` from top row only if the `ColC` is not null else 
if `ColB` is not null else `ColA` is not null

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between your actual and expected results are? Looks to me like they are just ordered by the last column descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
from Table 
where ColC = 7 or ColB = 2 or ColA = 10
ORDER BY ColC DESC, ColB DESC, ColA DESC
```